# Prevent user from copying URL from address bar

Tags: javascript, web, browser

I've looked around everywhere and it seems like there's no way of accomplishing what I need to do, but I thought I'd ask to see if anyone could think of a workaround.

I have this portal (intranet) where users can send some posts to their friends and family (job openings, basically), there's a link to send those by email, however users are copying the URL and sending it via email or texts, this URL however contains internal links that we don't want to be visible to others outside the company (yes they need a login anyway, but heads of IT are concerned)

We first thought of hiding the URL but as I understand, all browsers have disabled this option for a while now for security reasons (even IE since IE7).

The only other thing I could think of was to somehow prevent the users from copying the URL, sort of like a "readonly" or "disabled" text input, but haven't been able to find a way... I assume it cannot be done since the address bar is not actually within the site, therefore out of JavaScript control.

Can you guys think of any other workaround?

Comment: You can't, and you shouldn't.

Comment: LOL "heads of IT are concerned"

Comment: you could put your 'sensitive' information in an iframe, so the url would be hidden, but that does not prevent anyone from looking at it with any of the various tools embedded in the browser.

Comment: You have a password protection scheme in place. The only thing else I can think of is limiting the web server to only allow requests from users on a specific range of IP addresses.

Comment: One would wonder how they got to be `head of IT` in the first place, with such concerns.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your answers, I agree, it's pretty stupid, and they have security to access, there's even a different URL if you're outside the VPN and other things I don't quite understand. But they asked me about this and it's a huge multinational company (can't say the name obviously, but I'm sure you all use it regularly).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use history.pushState() to set the url bar to something that doesn't give away secrets. for example, run this in the console:

```
 history.pushState(null, null, "/");
```

After running, it now looks like you're on the stack home page, even though you are still on /questions/26537657/prevent-user-from-copying-url-from-address-bar/. it won't stop hackers, but it will prevent naive users from spilling the beans. you can use this to compose vanity urls as well as short ones. just make sure the server knows what to do with any url you generate because when you return via that url, it uses the server, and thus it will need to produce something meaningful.

edit: as kindly pointed out in comments,  history.pushState() create a new history entry. this might not be what you want if this page will papear mid-workflow, as opposed to a popup or other end destination. Uf that's the case, you should use it's non-creating counterpart:

```
 history.replaceState(null, null, "/");
```

That will just replace your current url in the address bar, without creating a new entry, so that back goes back.

There seems to be some confusion about pushState's implications on security. there is no such thing in client-side code. It bears repeating: "this won't stop hackers", it will just provides shorter bookmark-able URL to your users and prevent them from worrying the IT dept, regardless of the merits of IT's discomfort.

Comment: -1 for encouraging user-hostile behavior

Comment: well most users like having bookmarks that do what they want, i don't see how that's hostile. pushState() allows a nice separation between user-visible data (URLs) and physical asset locations, giving you migration flexibility, semantic urls, permalinks independent of CMSs, etc. in short, it's a very good thing, even if it is a bit new-fangled at this point...

Comment: Trying this now, will get back to you soon. Thanks!

Comment: I don't know what the merits of `pushState` and bookmarking has to do with a request to _hide information from the user_ which is the hostile behavior I'm referring to.

Comment: you're not hiding anything from the user (unless i'm mis-understanding something here), you're just giving them a handier and internally-comfortable path to get to that info. you're hiding stuff from the outside world, but nothing the user cares about. a path is just a path, might as well use a semantic one...

Comment: They don't want to hide the information from their users, they just don't want those URLs outside the company, since it is after all an intranet, and the users their employees. So if hiding is not an option, at least don't let them share it (so easily)

Comment: @DanielAlmaguer: you don't have to, and shouldn't discard the whole url. it's not my intention to suggest that (i like cool URLs), only to provide a way to distribute, for example, /url/fred22/  or /url/?name=fred22 instead of /users/fred22/, if you didn't want anyone knowing about /users/...

Comment: Exactly, that was the point, and your solution worked. Thanks a lot!

Comment: But now you've broken the back button, as hitting `back` will just replace the URL you erased.

Comment: @Mathletics: well if that's a concern, you can always use history.replaceState() to do the same thing...

Comment: This is a typical example of 'security by obscurity'. This method is easily 'broken', and will annoy the hell out of your users.

Comment: @Carpetsmoker: it's not about security, anyone can view-source, it's about preventing careless folks (read almost everyone) from angering the IT dept, admittedly over something stupid.